# Move buttons to the bottom right corner of the header

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a basic webpage.  I want to have buttons at the top for logging in or signing up, but I can't seem to get them to move to the bottom right of the header no matter what I do.  They usually just end up in the center, and I tried to float them but that definitely didn't work.  What's a good way to go about styling buttons in CSS?

HTML:

```css
    .clear {
 clear: both;
    }

    #container{
        margin: 0 auto;
        max-width: 1200px;
    }
    header {
        width: 94%;
        padding: 3%;
        background-color: #F3D22D;
    }
    header #title {
        font-size: 50px;
        color: #fff;
    }
    nav {
        width: 97%;
        background-color: #DDCFC5;
        padding: 0 1.5% 0 1.5%;
    }
    nav ul li {
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 15px 1.5% 15px 1.5% ;
    }
    nav ul li a {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #ffffff;
        font-size: 1.2em;
    }
     nav ul li a:hover {
         color: #000000;
         text-decoration: none;
     }
     #content {
        float: left;
        padding: 3%;
        width: 64%;
    }
    aside {
        float: right;
        padding: 3%;
        width: 24%;
        background-color: #DDCFC5;
    }
    footer{
        width: 94%;
        padding: 3%;
        background-color: #F3D22D;
        border-top: 5px solid #DDCFC5;
        color: #fff;
        text-align: center;
    }
    @media all and (max-width : 768px) {
        header {
            text-align: center;
        }
        nav {
            text-align: center;
        }
        #content {
            width: 94%;
            padding: 3%;
        }
        #sidebar {
            width: 94%;
            padding: 3%;
            border-top: 3px solid #E64A19;
        }
    }
    @media all and (max-width : 330px) {
        nav ul li {
            display:block;
            width: 94%;
        }
    }

    button {
     background-color: #4CAF50;
     border: none;
     color: white;
     padding: 15px 32px;
     text-align: center;
     text-decoration: none;
     display: inline-block;
     font-size: 16px;
     margin: 4px 2px;
     cursor: pointer;
    }

    #usermenu {
     bottom: 0;
     left: 0;
    }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
     <head>
  <title>Website</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link type="text/css? rel="stylesheet" href="reset.css" />
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="container">
   <!-- header -->
   <header id="header">
    <h1 id="title">Website</h1>
    <div id="usermenu">
     <button  type="button">Login</button>
     <button type="button">Sign Up</button>
    </div>
   </header>
   <!-- navigation -->
   <nav id="menu" class="clearfix">
    <ul>
     <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
   </nav>

       <!-- main content area -->
   
       <section id="content">
        <h2>Built with HTML5 and CSS3</h2>
        <p>
         More content here................
         <br>
         Hello... blah blahblah
        </p>
       </section>
   
       <!-- sidebar -->
       <aside id="sidebar">
        <h3>This is the sidebar</h3>
        <p>content goes here...</p>
       </aside>
       <div class="clear"></div>
       <!-- footer -->
       <footer id="footer" class="clearfix">
        Copyright &copy Gregory Soble 2017
       </footer>
      </div>
     </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Please revert to your original CSS at the time the question was asked, so that the code reflects your question.  This way it remains useful for other visitors.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default the `position` of an element is static, so values for `top`, `right`, `bottom`, and `left` have no effect at all.  You need to give the element/elements another value for `position` to be able to "position" them.

```css
.clear {
clear: both;
}

#container{
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 1200px;
}
header {
    position: relative;
    width: 94%;
    padding: 3%;
    background-color: #F3D22D;
}
header #title {
    font-size: 50px;
    color: #fff;
}
nav {
    width: 97%;
    background-color: #DDCFC5;
    padding: 0 1.5% 0 1.5%;
}
nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 15px 1.5% 15px 1.5% ;
}
nav ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 1.2em;
}
 nav ul li a:hover {
     color: #000000;
     text-decoration: none;
 }
 #content {
    float: left;
    padding: 3%;
    width: 64%;
}
aside {
    float: right;
    padding: 3%;
    width: 24%;
    background-color: #DDCFC5;
}
footer{
    width: 94%;
    padding: 3%;
    background-color: #F3D22D;
    border-top: 5px solid #DDCFC5;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
}
@media all and (max-width : 768px) {
    header {
        text-align: center;
    }
    nav {
        text-align: center;
    }
    #content {
        width: 94%;
        padding: 3%;
    }
    #sidebar {
        width: 94%;
        padding: 3%;
        border-top: 3px solid #E64A19;
    }
}
@media all and (max-width : 330px) {
    nav ul li {
        display:block;
        width: 94%;
    }
}

button {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 15px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 4px 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#usermenu {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

```html
    <div id="container">
        <!-- header -->
        <header id="header">
            <h1 id="title">Website</h1>
            <div id="usermenu">
                <button  type="button">Login</button>
                <button type="button">Sign Up</button>
            </div>
        </header>
        <!-- navigation -->
        <nav id="menu" class="clearfix">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>

            <!-- main content area -->

            <section id="content">
                <h2>Built with HTML5 and CSS3</h2>
                <p>
                    More content here................
                    <br>
                    Hello... blah blahblah
                </p>
            </section>

            <!-- sidebar -->
            <aside id="sidebar">
                <h3>This is the sidebar</h3>
                <p>content goes here...</p>
            </aside>
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <!-- footer -->
            <footer id="footer" class="clearfix">
                Copyright &copy Gregory Soble 2017
            </footer>
        </div>
```

Comment: Your example code works, but when I implement in with my existing CSS it breaks my CSS.  The head and body overlap.  Do I need to make all elements absolute to keep the positioning of everything else?

Comment: You don't have to add positioning for **everything** on the page.  You might need to position sibling elements to keep the rest of your layout, but it would be impossible to tell what else you would need there without knowing what your CSS looks like.

Comment: Hmm.  I'm still having some trouble.  I can't get the buttons out of the bottom left of the page without messing up the entire layout.  I added the rest of the code for the page.

Comment: All you really needed was to add `position: relative` to the `#header`, because `position: absolute` will position an item *relative* to it's nearest positioned parent.  In your case, it was the window, that's why the buttons where appearing at the bottom of the screen.  I updated the snippet in my answer to demonstrate.

Comment: That solved my issue.  Thanks for the newbie help.  This is my first time working with CSS.